# REGEX Bank Routing Number excluding specific set

Tags: php

I currently use REGEX pattern (`^[012346789][0-9]{8}$`) for validating US bank routing numbers.

No routing numbers begin with **5**, then any set of characters after that.

My problem is that I have one routing number that needs to be excluded, (**026009593**) and I need to not allow this to be accepted.

I have tried the following:

`([012346789][0-9]{8}+$)\b(^<!026009593)`

`^\b(?!026009593)([012346789][0-9]{8}+$)`

How could I allow basically any set to be validated minus this one specific number?

Comment: ([012346789][0-9]{8}+$)\b(^<!026009593) and ^\b(?!026009593)([012346789][0-9]{8}+$) -- Here is the string I have tried.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do the job:

```
([012346789][0-9]{8}$)\b(?<!026009593)
```

Basically, you used a `^` instead of `?`

This also Works:

```
\b(?!026009593)[012346789][0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly in regex101, however I am getting an "invalid regular expression" error in my document?!!  ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered.  I used a ^ instead of ? and had what appears to be too many groupings.